# Are “could I have been able to cope with” and "could I have coped with” the same?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, conditional-perfect, can-vs-be-able

I am a bit confused with the formation of this sentence.  My lines are:

> What if I were a girl? **Would I have been able to cope** with the ordeal that women and girls live through every day?

But I am still confused about whether writing *would I have been able to* is the correct form.

Would it still be correct if I change that to

> What if I were a girl? **Could I have coped** with the ordeal that women and girls live through every day?

Comment: Both say the same. "to be able to" is just a more fancy expression for "can" and your grammar is correct for both. So it's just a matter of taste, which one you use.

Comment: So you mean to say that it won't be incorrect if I say "Would I have been able to cope with....?". Can I go with it?

Comment: Absolutely. Like I said, the meaning is the same and both are grammatically correct.

Comment: Please look at the many related [tag:can-vs-be-able] questions, and possibly also the [tag:conditional-perfect] questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Would is better as it's expressing a hypothetical subjunctive. That's also why it's correctly "if I were a girl" and not the incorrect "if I was a girl".

Comment: I was going to disagree with this, then I thought about it and realised you are right. _Could_ is still possible, but in a way ambiguous because it could also be used in a _realis_ case, whereas _would_ definitely takes it into the _irrealis_ (hypothetical). Here, since the previous sentence makes it clearly hypothetical either will do, but in general _would_ is better.

Comment: Thank you Colin :)) Yeah, I finally settled for "would".